# Placing an external Javascript in a Php file

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have an external Javascript that should go in the head section of an html type document, however my site is strictly php.

```
<?php
$the_title = 'Welcome!';
$the_content = '<p>We are still working out the kinks!  The sign up page works, so feel free to sign up!  We will send out a welcome message when we finish!  Cheers.<br />
<form action="http://meledie39spicks.wildapricot.org/Sys/Login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="browserData" id="idLoginBoxBrowserField">

        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">
        <label for="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">Remember me</label>
        <input type="submit" class="loginBoxLoginButton" tabindex="4" value="Login">
    </form>';
?>

<?php include('single.php'); ?>
```

I need to place the javascript:

```
  <script src="http://www.wildapricot.com/docs/scripts/waloginbox.js></script>
```

somewhere in order for the form to work.  I tried placing it directly after the form, which worked to a degree with a major glitch.  I also tried echoing the script after the form in which my code editor told me that there was a syntax error.  I'm still new to code so now I'm at a loss.  Any other suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: You could either echo out the HTML or you could include the javascript file where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `echo` it out, where you need.

```
echo '<script src="http://www.wildapricot.com/docs/scripts/waloginbox.js></script>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, However I'm getting an error message when I try to load the page on the site.  It's telling me that there's a syntax error on that line when I try to echo it.

Comment: can you update you code as well, with echo statement I've suggested

Comment: Ok, fixed the syntax error; however that major glitch is still there.  I'm trying to plug a widget login form into my site.  The code seems right, but when I try to login, the widget forwards me over to the external site instead of logging me into my site (which is what it should do).  The tech support from this service has no clue about php code and that the login form should work with this java script they provided...:/  Which is why I'm here....

Comment: It's not much information you've shared, to suggest you where exactly the error is. Better to check their docs (the plugin you were using), and if you still not find any solution, you can raise a separate question

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to write in comment but that did not happened.

```
 <?php
 echo  '<script src="http://www.wildapricot.com/docs/scripts/waloginbox.js"></script>';
 echo $the_title = 'Welcome!';
 echo $the_content = '<p>We are still working out the kinks!  The sign up page works, so feel free to sign up!  We will send out a welcome message when we finish!  Cheers.<br />
    <form action="http://meledie39spicks.wildapricot.org/Sys/Login" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="browserData" id="idLoginBoxBrowserField">

    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">
    <label for="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">Remember me</label>
    <input type="submit" class="loginBoxLoginButton" tabindex="4" value="Login">
</form>';
  ?>

  <?php include('single.php'); ?>
```

You need to `echo` this in the top section of the file.

Comment: @Xrhapsodiex you should echo your PHP variables to display their values on the web page.

Comment: ok tried it again.  still the same thing.  I think there may be an error in the external javascript as it doesn't matter where I put it, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: also put echo functions in the script to mirror yours, it just doubled my page except it placed it in the upper right hand corner of my page.  It works perfect without the extra echo functions.

Comment: I used echo to display the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<script src="http://www.wildapricot.com/docs/scripts/waloginbox.js"></script>';
$the_title = 'Welcome!';
$the_content = '<p>We are still working out the kinks!  The sign up page works, so feel free to sign up!  We will send out a welcome message when we finish!  Cheers.<br /></p>

<form action="http://meledie39spicks.wildapricot.org/Sys/Login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="browserData" id="idLoginBoxBrowserField">

        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">
        <label for="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">Remember me</label>
        <input type="submit" class="loginBoxLoginButton" tabindex="4" value="Login">
    </form>'; 

?>

<?php include('single.php'); ?>
```

Comment: To display you should echo your php variables. check my answer now.